# SQlite writes a 0 instead of my data

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having an issue updating a record in an sqlite database in an android app using Xamarin. This is the table CREATE:

```
 CREATE TABLE [tickets] (key ntext, json ntext, last_refreshed text)
```

This is the UPDATE statement:

```
 UPDATE [tickets] SET [json]=@json AND [last_refreshed] = datetime('now') WHERE [key] = @key
```

And this is my code to write the data. I've confirmed that the data in the "data" and "key" variables is the desired data, and that the TICKET_TABLE_UPDATE constant is the one being used, but for some reason when I read the record from the sqlite database, there's a "0" in the json field, and the last_refreshed field hasn't been updated. Any ideas?

```
    public void WriteTicket(JiraTicket ticket) {
        int count = 0;
        using (SqliteCommand com = con.CreateCommand()) {
            com.CommandText = TICKET_TABLE_COUNT;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", ticket.Key);
            count = int.Parse(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }
        using (SqliteCommand com = con.CreateCommand()) {
            if (count > 0) {
                com.CommandText = TICKET_TABLE_UPDATE;
            } else {
                com.CommandText = TICKET_TABLE_INSERT;
            }

            String data = ticket.JSON;
            String key = ticket.Key;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@json", data);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: If it makes any difference, the string being written is rather long, maybe a couple dozen thousand characters.

Comment: This is using mono.data.sqlite

Comment: sqlite's max text length is in the multitude of millions so you should be fine. Maybe its something to do with your data type. I don't think ntext is supported.

Comment: If it's not supported, then why does it create the table? And the initial insert works, it only writes the 0 on an update statement.

Comment: By not supported I meant more like not defined by documentation. My experience with SQLite has shown that it can be very flexible when it comes to data types. But you are using a data type that SQLite hasn't explicitly said how it will be treated, so results may not be predictable.

Comment: Interesting...that's a fair point. I'll try switching the data type to text, see what I get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "AND" in your update statement with a comma to separate your field updates